# Handling timeout with Alert View - iOS

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, uialertview, nsurlrequest

Is it possible to handle a request timeout with a UIAlert? I would like to inform the user that there has been a time out. I set `0.0` just for testing to see if it would occur. The log does not print out so i do not believe i am handling correcting

```
request.timeoutInterval=0.0;
```

and to handle it:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
if(error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut){
    NSLog(@"Time out");
   }
}
```

I am using `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate`

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an error at all? How did you setup and start the `NSURLConnection`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982598/nsurlconnection-didfailwitherror-not-called

Comment: Try setting the timeout interval to 1. The docs don't say but I would expect zero to be treated as invalid.

Comment: Also I understand the system imposes a minimum time so you should wait several minutes to see if in fact it does return that code. Add another log to show exactly what the code is if not the one you test for.

Comment: @Wain thanks for the feedback, i tried setting it to 1, no luck.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper i set it up like so `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];`

Comment: @DavidH the error that is printed is `error -1009` is there anyway to simulate a timeout delay? I got this error above because I turned off wifi so Im guessing its a network error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a list of all the relevant error codes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/Reference/reference.html). Note that -1009 is `kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet`. To force a timeout, you need to have the ability to suppress the actual sending of the URL, or find one that just goes into a black hole.

Apple bundles `Network Link Conditioner` with Xcode (its in the networking tools I believe). There is a great article on this tool [on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/).

Another way (I believe) to get a timeout is to immediately after sending a request is to switch to another app, putting yours in the background. Wait 5 minutes, switch back, and look at the log. What you can do is in a demo app continually send out NSURLConnections - that is, once the first returns, send another. so there is always one outstanding. Now switch your app out - switch to another app in the simulator - wait, then return. You should be able to catch the condition this way, you can see the affect of changing the `timeoutinterval` value.

There was a long thread about timeouts in the private Apple forums for iOS networking - you may be able to find it. In the end, the system enforces a reasonably long minimum (as I recall), and you may be able to make it longer but not shorter. This hidden behavior has for sure baffled many people. The responder to the question was `Quinn "The Eskimo"`, one of Apple's most experienced networking engineers.

Comment: Great feedback!! thank you. This is very interesting. Its a pity there isnt a 'silver bullet' for creating a timeout.

Comment: @Gman there well may be a silver bullet - I just don't know of it. For sure using Network Conditioner, you can stop all traffic using that tool - this will for sure generate a timeout.

Comment: Hah - I'm answering as many questions as I can - I'm very close to a major milestone :-) Seriously, glad to help! That tool is for sure way underused, and can really help developers better test their code in a realistic fashion (crappy network where user is canceling long running operations etc).

Comment: I hope you get to that milestone :) thanks again for your help - you could always try and answer some of my unanswered questions (multipart objects in iOS) ;)